# Using foreach loop with Query Builder in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

For some reason this isn't working. The error I get is "Undefined index: cu_id" for the line

```
$cu_id = $rows['cu_id'];
```

I think I'm just totally using the querybuilder wrong with the foreach loop. Any help with the proper syntax for this? Thanks!

```
$query = new Query;

            $query->select('cu_id')->from('cu_emails')->where(['creator_id' => $user_id, 'email' => $email]);


    foreach ($query as $rows) {

            $cu_id = $rows['cu_id'];

            echo"CU ID: $cu_id<br /><br />";

    }
```

Also I'm on the Yii 2 framework in case anyone missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query not run.

```
$query->all()
```

and then foreach records
or

```
$query->one()
```

and get data from one record

```
$query = new Query;
$query->select('cu_id')->from('cu_emails')->where(['creator_id' => $user_id, 'email' => $email])
$results = $query->all();

foreach ($results as $rows) {
        $cu_id = $rows['cu_id'];
        echo"CU ID: $cu_id<br /><br />";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add all() or one() for getting the rows

```
$query = new Query;

   $myModels=   $query->select('cu_id')
       ->from('cu_emails')
       ->where(['creator_id' => $user_id, 'email' => $email])
       ->all();
```

and obtained the models in $myModels

```
foreach ($myModels as $rows) {

        $cu_id = $rows['cu_id'];

        echo"CU ID: $cu_id<br /><br />";

}
```

Comment: My error is gone, but it doesn't actually loop through the query with any data. What's a good way to debug my query?

Comment: Loop without echo a value for cu_id or don't loop ?

Comment: This was close, but $rows->cu_id didn't work in this instance. The solution above with $rows['cu_id'] worked.